# How to connect to Google Maps API v2 on Android

Tags: google-maps, authentication, google-maps-android-api-2, heatmap

I'm having a hard time connecting to the Google Maps API via the Heatmap demo app (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils). I followed the instructions at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/heatmap to set up my project and it runs, but the problem is the map doesn't show up on the screen and I get these errors in logcat:

```
I/Google Maps Android API(31950): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.

E/Google Maps Android API(31950): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I added the following to my Manifest (`<MY_API_KEY>` is the value I got from https://code.google.com/apis/console, had to upload my SHA1 key followed by a semicolon 
";" and the package name "com.google.maps.android.utils.demo"):

```
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="<MY_API_KEY>"/>
```

Any ideas on how to get the authentication working? (assuming that's the problem)

Comment: I tried that demo before and it worked for me so there is most likely an issue with the API key. The package name you listed is correct so your SHA1 is probably the culprit.  What OS and IDE are you using? Is the SHA1 from the debug keystore?

Comment: sorry for the slow response, I'm using Eclipse on Mac OS, haven't had a chance to test this out again